# setOnItemClickListener gives a compile error in ListView activity

Tags: android, listview

I have been following a tutorial on ListView and the following code gives errors. I have searched all the forums I can find but I keep coming up with the same recommended code. Maybe all the forums are quoting old versions and perhaps Android has moved on.

Anyway, here is the code and the error message:

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
 //@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) 
 {
 // TODO Sort out error and add function code
 }
 });
```

Error message:

```
 Multiple markers at this line

 -The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in the type
  AdapterView <ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new   OnItemClickListener(){})

 -OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

Any offers?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to solve this by specifying the parent class of **onItemClickListener** like this:

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
 //@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) 
 {
 // TODO Sort out error and add function code
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest like that,If there is ListView, `extends ListActivity` and handle listitem click in `onListItemClick`

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        //handle listitem click.
    }
```